# javascript, js chart looping issues

Tags: javascript, jscharts

Below code works fine for 3 students data that is hard coded. I need to generalise it to work with any number of students.

Making a stack column bar chart report using jscharts.

```
var barChartData = {
            labels: ['1A', '1B', '1C', '1D', '1E', '1F'],
            datasets: [{
                label: student_name[0],
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.red,
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [
                    oneA[0],
                    oneB[0],
                    oneC[0],
                    oneD[0],
                    oneE[0],
                    oneF[0] 
                ]
},
{
                label: student_name[1],
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [
                    oneA[1],
                    oneB[1],
                    oneC[1],
                    oneD[1],
                    oneE[1],
                    oneF[1] 
                ]
},
{
                label: student_name[2],
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                stack: 'Stack 0',
                data: [
                    oneA[2],
                    oneB[2],
                    oneC[2],
                    oneD[2],
                    oneE[2],
                    oneF[2] 
                ]
} 


]}
```

Comment: you should consider adding a little bit more code, perhaps even the full file either here or on an external code sandbox. in the current form, we are not sure what you have tried, so cannot suggest what you can do next.

Comment: 'loop it correctly' is subjective.  You need to specify what that loop is supposed to do.

Comment: You can see student_name[0] , student_name[1],student_name[2] instead of this hard coding i want it to be looped